# Ambulance, (or hearse) synonym beginning with z?

Tags: synonyms

I have a memory of a word like zephirchain or zephyrchain that I heard as a lyric in a song by Mike Oldfield. When I search the lyric websites they seem to have heard something else. (Maybe I "kissed the sky" when I should have been doing something else?)

From the context of the song it sounded like it was an ambulance of a hearse.

The synonym and dictionary websites also don't make any useful suggestions that I can find.

Does such a word exist or am I suffering from the Rashomon effect?

Edit: Sorry. The song was "Crime of Passion" The word is at the end of the tenth or so line, that starts, "And then he saw her moving away in a ..."  about 1:23 into the song ( vimeo. com/14715762 has a recording.)

Clarification: My ears and brain strongly disagree with the lyric websites, (which is why I deliberately didn't list the song in the first place.) I memorised this song before the fist website was ever written. If the lyric websites are wrong then just quoting the from them isn't helping. I grew up with my brain soaked in British regional accents, and none of them, (that I can manage) stretch to a person's name in this particular lyric. I would ask Oldfield, but by now he might be an unreliable narrator because of extensive assisted musical exploration.

Comment: sepulcher/sepulchre?

Comment: What song? What do the lyric sites say is the word?

Comment: catafalque? ? ?

Comment: You have to find the title of the song to delay having your question closed. We will even work by listening to a clip. But a while goos chaise leaves us at a loss of how to help.

Comment: Not enough information here. We need the benefit of the *entire* context -- you haven't even said what the "something else" might be, or the song involved, and yet you must know the title if you have found a site thinks it's something else. Please give as much information as possible.

Comment: I find this online ... "He Looked Outside The Frosty Window Pane / And Then He Saw Her Moving Away Elizabeth Jane"  but it does seem the video is something else.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question; interpretation / conversion of speech to text are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words are here. Having listened, I can confirm that the following is correct. The way the woman's name is pronounced places the syllable stress unusually - this is to fit in with the tune.

He pronounces it as eliz-**A**-beth jane with the accent on the "A" syllable. Normally this would be pronounced e-LIZ-abeth jane.

> He stood to see if he could catch her breathing
>
> But it was no good, he understood she was leaving.
>
> He looked outside the frosty window pane
>
> And then he saw her moving away, Elizabeth Jane.

https://www.metrolyrics.com/crime-of-passion-lyrics-mike-oldfield.html

---

P.S. Note that "Jane" rhymes with "pane" from the previous line.

Comment: I've seen the lyrics sites and they feel auto-generated or from a different performance than the one on my record. I posed this question precicely because my ears don't hear it that way, and it seems poeticly clunky for Oldfield, (even if he was emotionally distressed.)

Comment: @Alexx Roche - Thanks for your comment. I'm not quite sure what you are saying. I answered from having listened to the song and from what I heard. I referred to a text that supported my understanding. As a musician I could write the words and music to show how the unusual emphasis works if that would helpful.

Comment: Thank you chasly. You have already been too kind. I'm probably wrong, so don't worry.